# Check if logged in with same Facebook Account - Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing an issue and would be awesome if someone can suggest me how to resolve...

I am trying to connect USER1 to Facebook via its PHP API, it works - I save the access token in the DB and use it to access USER1's account information (photos) the next time USER1 logs in.

Lets say for example, USER1 goes to the another computer where USER2 is already logged into Facebook. When USER1 opens his account on his PC, I automatically check for the login via the below javascript function with the saved USER1 token.

`FB.getLoginStatus`

Can I put a check here to see if USER1 is the one who has logged into Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you request user to key in there in-apps username or password? If yes, maybe you database can log facebook ID, linked with in-apps username. So you can basically check this and notify user if facebook return ID and database facebook ID is not match.

If you do not, maybe you can show currect facebook log-in account name in somewhere, and state "not xxxx?" (check you google account, it using this method).

Comment: Well, I think this idea of using the id is great and simple. Cheers!